# Hide a range in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

How do I hide a range in VBA Excel 2010?

For example i want to hide

> range("A1:A3")

some help would be appreciated

Comment: Let me Google that for you...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx  _3.  Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You can always record a macro and then just clean it up. It can give you a good idea of the basics of VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide a range with these dimensions in Excel. Excel allows hiding complete rows or complete columns, but not just a few cells in a column.